# Set order of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to reorder columns in pandas dataframe based on my personal preference (i.e. not alphabetically or numerically sorted, but more like following certain conventions)?

Simple example:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({
        'one thing':[1,2,3,4],
        'second thing':[0.1,0.2,1,2],
        'other thing':['a','e','i','o']})
```

produces this:

```
   one thing other thing  second thing
0          1           a           0.1
1          2           e           0.2
2          3           i           1.0
3          4           o           2.0
```

But instead, I would like this:

```
   one thing second thing  other thing
0          1           0.1           a
1          2           0.2           e
2          3           1.0           i
3          4           2.0           o
```

(Please, provide a generic solution rather than specific to this case. Many thanks.)

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Just select the order yourself by typing in the column names. Note the double brackets:

```
frame = frame[['column I want first', 'column I want second'...etc.]]
```

Comment: This only works with this rather small example. If you are reading data in from another source, like a csv file or a database table, you can't use this answer. And those seem to be much more common. The OP requested a general solution.

Comment: This is obviously a general solution. Even if you read column names and orders from a different csv file, you can extract column names to list and use above notation easily. What is the non-general point of this answer?

Comment: To do operations over the list of column names instead of typing them, remember that you can access them like this `list(frame.columns)`, or similar.

Comment: I agree with `alecelik` and disagree with `chrisfs` - I used a column of the same dataframe, length 638, to reorder the columns, which had titles the same as the entries in that column. In a square dataframe, I applied the same permutation to rows and columns. `df_MPs1 = df_MPs1[[pid for pid in df_MPs1['person_id']]]`

Answer (score 153):

You can use this:

```
columnsTitles = ['onething', 'secondthing', 'otherthing']

frame = frame.reindex(columns=columnsTitles)
```

Comment: Even though most other solutions are more concise, I would consider this one to be the most readable for anybody who is not 100% familiar with `pandas`.

Comment: Remember to assign the return value to a variable though, this does not modify column order in-place (at least not in `pandas` v0.23`).

Comment: This works for me thanks?

Comment: Great suggestion, and most probably the easiest to understand if you are a newcomer to Pandas.

Comment: This is a really dangerous method: if you miss-spell a column name pandas will create a new column filled with NaN instead of raising an error!

Answer (score 90):

### UPDATE:

There is a useful package called [`pyjanitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/). It improves pandas usability by providing many useful R-style API and is neatly integrated with pandas.

In particular, to reorder columns, you can simply do the following.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import janitor
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1, 1], "col2": [2, 2, 2], "col3": [3, 3, 3]})
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3
>>> df.reorder_columns(['col3', 'col1'])
   col3  col1  col2
0     3     1     2
1     3     1     2
2     3     1     2
```

---

Here is a solution I use very often. When you have a large data set with tons of columns, you definitely do not want to manually rearrange all the columns.

What you can and, most likely, want to do is to just order the first a few columns that you frequently use, and let all other columns just be themselves. This is a common approach in R. `df %>%select(one, two, three, everything())`

So you can first manually type the columns that you want to order and to be positioned before all the other columns in a list `cols_to_order`.

Then you construct a list for new columns by combining the rest of the columns:

```
new_columns = cols_to_order + (frame.columns.drop(cols_to_order).tolist())
```

After this, you can use the `new_columns` as other solutions suggested.

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'one thing': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'other thing': ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o'],
    'more things': ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o'],
    'second thing': [0.1, 0.2, 1, 2],
})

cols_to_order = ['one thing', 'second thing']
new_columns = cols_to_order + (frame.columns.drop(cols_to_order).tolist())
frame = frame[new_columns]

   one thing  second thing other thing more things
0          1           0.1           a           a
1          2           0.2           e           e
2          3           1.0           i           i
3          4           2.0           o           o
```

Comment: brilliant, perfect.  thank you for keeping me from having to type out every column name or index

Comment: How is that difficult to do this in pandas ffs? df %>% relocate(new_col) all day.
## ---- ##
You could make that a function:
def relocate(df, var):
    new_var_order = [var] + df.columns.drop(var).tolist()
    df = df[new_var_order]
    return(df)

Answer (score 31):

You could also do something like `df = df[['x', 'y', 'a', 'b']]`

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'one thing':[1,2,3,4],'second thing':[0.1,0.2,1,2],'other thing':['a','e','i','o']})
frame = frame[['second thing', 'other thing', 'one thing']]
print frame
   second thing other thing  one thing
0           0.1           a          1
1           0.2           e          2
2           1.0           i          3
3           2.0           o          4
```

Also, you can get the list of columns with:

```
cols = list(df.columns.values)
```

The output will produce something like this:

```
['x', 'y', 'a', 'b']
```

Which is then easy to rearrange manually.

Answer (score 13):

Construct it with a list instead of a dictionary

```
frame = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, .1, 'a'],
        [2, .2, 'e'],
        [3,  1, 'i'],
        [4,  4, 'o']
    ], columns=['one thing', 'second thing', 'other thing'])

frame

   one thing  second thing other thing
0          1           0.1           a
1          2           0.2           e
2          3           1.0           i
3          4           4.0           o
```

Comment: I could not get 'column name': data to work inside a list as it does in a dict.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use OrderedDict:

```
In [183]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [184]: data = OrderedDict()

In [185]: data['one thing'] = [1,2,3,4]

In [186]: data['second thing'] = [0.1,0.2,1,2]

In [187]: data['other thing'] = ['a','e','i','o']

In [188]: frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [189]: frame
Out[189]:
   one thing  second thing other thing
0          1           0.1           a
1          2           0.2           e
2          3           1.0           i
3          4           2.0           o
```

Answer (score 7):

Add the 'columns' parameter:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({
        'one thing':[1,2,3,4],
        'second thing':[0.1,0.2,1,2],
        'other thing':['a','e','i','o']},
        columns=['one thing', 'second thing', 'other thing']
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try indexing (so you want a generic solution not only for this, so index order can be just what you want):

```
l=[0,2,1] # index order
frame=frame[[frame.columns[i] for i in l]]
```

Now:

```
print(frame)
```

Is:

```
   one thing second thing  other thing
0          1           0.1           a
1          2           0.2           e
2          3           1.0           i
3          4           2.0           o
```

Answer (score 7):

Even though it's an old question, you can also use `loc` and `iloc`:

```
frame = frame.loc[:, ['column I want first', 'column I want second', "other thing"]]

frame = frame.iloc[:, [1, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: This is a great one if you want to do it by position, not name of column

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.reindex(columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be the most straightforward and working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'one thing':[1,2,3,4],
        'second thing':[0.1,0.2,1,2],
        'other thing':['a','e','i','o']})

df = df[['one thing','second thing', 'other thing']]
```