# How to change the order of columns while converting to excel in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary, 'values', in Python. The 'values' contains lists of integers, except the 'RowHeaders'. 
I would like to have the 'RowHeaders' as the first column in the excel file. In the following code, I cannot add a condition in 'from_items' method to put it as the first column. When I run this code, it doesn't put the 'RowHeaders' data in the first column.

```
values['RowHeaders'] = list_of_headers

for feat in features:
    values.setdefault(feat, list())
    for p in data:
        values[feat].append(int(data[p][feat]))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([(f,values[f]) for f in values])
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)    
writer.save()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some data, then it is easier to help. And also change the tag, this is a pandas not a scipy question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I update the description and the code.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `values`? You might also want to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148429/2000793) and/or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41968732/2000793).

Comment: @EricEdLohmar The first linked worked for me!