# Set order of mulitindexed columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to reorder specific levels within the columns index in a Pandas dataframe based on my personal preference (e.g., by an ordered list)?

```
In [130]: frame = pd.DataFrame({
     ...: ('TWO','thing1'):[1,2,3,4],
     ...: ('TWO','thing4'):[1,2,3,4],
     ...: ('DARK','thing1'):[0.1,0.2,1,2],
     ...: ('ANTS','thing3'):['a','e','i','o'],
     ...: ('ANTS','thing1'):['a','e','i','o']})

In [131]: frame
Out[131]: 
    ANTS          DARK    TWO       
  thing1 thing3 thing1 thing1 thing4
0      a      a    0.1      1      1
1      e      e    0.2      2      2
2      i      i    1.0      3      3
3      o      o    2.0      4      4
```

My list is then based on a separately generated list.  Important to note that I don't know either `level 0` or `level 1` index labels - they are variables.

```
In [132]: sort_list = ['DARK', 'ANTS', 'TWO']
```

If I then try and pass this list in the context of `frame = frame[sort_list]` or `.reindex(columns=sort_list)` it throws `Expected tuple, got str` for obvious reasons.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) are the solutions that worked on a single level index.

What I'd like to do is only sort on the top level and leave the second level as is.  The final dataframe looking like this...

```
  DARK   ANTS           TWO       
thing1 thing1 thing3 thing1 thing4
   0.1      a      a      1      1
   0.2      e      e      2      2
   1.0      i      i      3      3
   2.0      o      o      4      4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using `reindex`

```
frame.reindex(sort_list, level=0, axis=1)
Out[126]: 
    DARK   ANTS           TWO       
  thing1 thing1 thing3 thing1 thing4
0    0.1      a      a      1      1
1    0.2      e      e      2      2
2    1.0      i      i      3      3
3    2.0      o      o      4      4
```

Comment: I almost had it.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

You can sort the index then slice

```
frame.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)[['DARK', 'ANTS', 'TWO']]

    DARK   ANTS           TWO       
  thing1 thing1 thing3 thing1 thing4
0    0.1      a      a      1      1
1    0.2      e      e      2      2
2    1.0      i      i      3      3
3    2.0      o      o      4      4
```

---

### Option 2

Set the first level of the columns to be categorical that is ordered

```
frame.columns = frame.columns.set_levels(
    pd.CategoricalIndex(
        frame.columns.levels[0],
        ['DARK', 'ANTS', 'TWO'],
        ordered=True
    ), level=0
)

frame.sort_index(axis=1)

    DARK   ANTS           TWO       
  thing1 thing1 thing3 thing1 thing4
0    0.1      a      a      1      1
1    0.2      e      e      2      2
2    1.0      i      i      3      3
3    2.0      o      o      4      4
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared, another, previously unknown, method... :-)  I don't think I've made it a day without seeing something new.