# Load a dataframe from json array in order

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following array in python:

```
[
    {'id': [1,2,3]},
    {'name': [4,3,2]},
    {'age': [9,0,1]},
]
```

How would I load this into a pandas dataframe? Usually I do `pd.DataFrame` from a dict, but it's important for me to maintain the column order.

The final data should look like this:

```
id     name       age
1      4          9
2      3          0
3      2          1
```

Comment: how you need the final data to look ?

Comment: @n1tk updated with output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a single dictionary and then feed to `pd.DataFrame`. To guarantee column ordering is preserved, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

L = [{'id': [1,2,3]},
     {'name': [4,3,2]},
     {'age': [9,0,1]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([(k, v) for d in L for k, v in d.items()]))

print(df)

   id  name  age
0   1     4    9
1   2     3    0
2   3     2    1
```

With Python 3.7+ [dictionaries are insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), so you can use a regular `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or merge the list of dictionaries ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495395/1293700)) and convert the result to a dataframe:

```
merged_data = {}

[merged_data.update(d) for d in original_data]    
# or, b/c it's more pythonic:
# list(map(lambda x: merged_data.update(x), original_data))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(merged_data)
df = df[['id', 'name', 'age']]

print(df)

# id  name  age
# 0   1     4    9
# 1   2     3    0
# 2   3     2    1
```

For me it's more clear and readable.

Comment: how do you know that the `dict` will preserve ordering? Is that an OrderedDict, or ?

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood your question. Nevertheless did you think about [reordering the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968766/1293700)?

Comment: I completed the example.

Answer (score 0):

A little hacky, but does

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d_) for d_ in d], axis=1)
```

work?

(assuming

```
d = your_list
```

)

Comment: that works, thanks. Could you please explain what `axis=1` does?

Comment: sure! `axis=0` is the default, and will concatenate dataframes vertically (ie if you have two dataframes of three columns and three rows, `axis=0` will make one with three columns and six rows. `axis=1` is the opposite, concatenates them horizontally, so you would have 6 columns and 3 rows. Since in this case you are creating 3 new dataframes of 3 rows and 1 column, to get the resulting 3x3 df you need to use `axis=1`. (more infor here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)