# specify a first column when exporting csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, variables

Wondering how to specify a first column using pandas?

For example, I have a dataframe `df` with variables `var1, var2, var3,...varx`, I would like the first column to be `var3` in the csv generated.

`df.to_csv('location/export.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set order of columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Would the resulting ordering be [var3, var1, var2, var4,..., varX] or [var3, var4 ... varX, var1, var2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rearrange the columns in any way you want by doing

```
df[['var3', 'var1', 'var2', ..., 'varx']].to_csv('location/export.csv', index=False)
```

If you just want to have var3 in the beginning, there's a less manual way in

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('var3')
df[['var3'] + cols].to_csv('location/export.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks - I have a long list of variables and really just care about the first column.

Comment: @AnneHsiao Be sure to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it solved the problem. Welcome to SO!