# Python pandas export mongodb collection to CSV columns out of order

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have a Python script the creates a list of EC2 instances in all of our AWS accounts (about 150) and stores the result in MongoDB.

I'm exporting the  mongodb collection to a CSV file with the Python pandas module. It works except that the headers are out of order, and I don't want to print the MongoDB Index.

In the original version of the script (before adding the database) I was using the CSV module to write the file and the headers are correct:
[image: csv file output no mongo]

I've added the database both as a learning exercise and because it makes it easier to work through all the Amazon accounts we have.

If I look at the json in the mongo database for the collection I'm printing all of the fields are in the correct order:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f14f9ffa40de31278dade03'), 'AWS Account': 'jf-master-pd', 'Account Number': '123456789101', 'Name': 'usawsweb001', 'Instance ID': 'i-01e5e920b4d3d5dcb', 'AMI ID': 'ami-006219aba10688d0b', 'Volumes': 'vol-0ce8db4e071bc7229, vol-099f6d212a91121d0, vol-0bb36e343e9c01374, vol-05610645edfd02253, vol-05adc01d70d75d649', 'Private IP': '172.31.62.168', 'Public IP': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'Private DNS': 'ip-172-31-62-168.ec2.internal', 'Availability Zone': 'us-east-1e', 'VPC ID': 'vpc-68b1ff12', 'Type': 't2.micro', 'Key Pair Name': 'jf-timd', 'State': 'running', 'Launch Date': 'July 20 2020'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5f14f9ffa40de31278dade05'), 'AWS Account': 'jf-master-pd', 'Account Number': '123456789101', 'Name': 'usawsweb002', 'Instance ID': 'i-0b7db2bcab853ef96', 'AMI ID': 'ami-006219aba10688d0b', 'Volumes': 'vol-095a9dcf54ca97c0e, vol-0c8e96b71fbb7dfcf, vol-070c16c457f91c54e, vol-0dc1eaf2e826fa3a6, vol-0f0f157a8489ab939', 'Private IP': '172.31.63.131', 'Public IP': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'Private DNS': 'ip-172-31-63-131.ec2.internal', 'Availability Zone': 'us-east-1e', 'VPC ID': 'vpc-68b1ff12', 'Type': 't2.micro', 'Key Pair Name': 'jf-timd', 'State': 'running', 'Launch Date': 'July 20 2020'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5f14f9ffa40de31278dade07'), 'AWS Account': 'jf-master-pd', 'Account Number': '123456789101', 'Name': 'usawsweb003', 'Instance ID': 'i-0611acf4b6cc53b61', 'AMI ID': 'ami-006219aba10688d0b', 'Volumes': 'vol-0aa28f89f6ce50577, vol-0e37ff844e8b9c47a, vol-0d54c713ae231739c, vol-0e29df46edc814619, vol-07e0c40a8913b1d31', 'Private IP': '172.31.52.44', 'Public IP': 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'Private DNS': 'ip-172-31-52-44.ec2.internal', 'Availability Zone': 'us-east-1e', 'VPC ID': 'vpc-68b1ff12', 'Type': 't2.micro', 'Key Pair Name': 'jf-timd', 'State': 'running', 'Launch Date': 'July 20 2020'}
```

But using python pandas to export from the mongo database the headers are out of whack. The info lines up to the correct header, but the columns are completely out of order:

[image: csv file mongo output]

In my code I'm creating a dictionary with the server info in it, then passing the dictionary to the function that prints the Mongo collection :

```
def list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive, regions, show_details, instance_col):
for region in regions:
    if 'gov' in aws_account and not 'admin' in aws_account:
        try:
            session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region)
        except botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound as e:
            profile_missing_message = f"An exception has occurred: {e}"
            account_found = 'no'
            raise
    else:
        try:
            session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region)
            account_found = 'yes'
        except botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound as e:
            profile_missing_message = f"An exception has occurred: {e}"
            raise
    try:
        ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
    message = f"  Region: {region} in {aws_account}: ({aws_account_number})  "
    banner(message)

    print(Fore.RESET)
    # Loop through the instances
    try:
        instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
        for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
                for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
                    instance_count = instance_count + 1
                    launch_time = instance["LaunchTime"]
                    launch_time_friendly = launch_time.strftime("%B %d %Y")
                    tree = objectpath.Tree(instance)
                    block_devices = set(tree.execute('$..BlockDeviceMappings[\'Ebs\'][\'VolumeId\']'))
                    if block_devices:
                        block_devices = list(block_devices)
                        block_devices = str(block_devices).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        block_devices = None
                    private_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))
                    if private_ips:
                        private_ips_list = list(private_ips)
                        private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        private_ips_list = None
                    public_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PublicIp'))
                    if len(public_ips) == 0:
                        public_ips = None
                    if public_ips:
                        public_ips_list = list(public_ips)
                        public_ips_list = str(public_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        public_ips_list = None
                    name = None
                    if 'Tags' in instance:
                        try:
                            tags = instance['Tags']
                            name = None
                            for tag in tags:
                                if tag["Key"] == "Name":
                                    name = tag["Value"]
                                if tag["Key"] == "Engagement" or tag["Key"] == "Engagement Code":
                                    engagement = tag["Value"]
                        except ValueError:
                            # print("Instance: %s has no tags" % instance_id)
                            raise
                    key_name = instance['KeyName'] if instance['KeyName'] else None
                    vpc_id = instance.get('VpcId') if instance.get('VpcId') else None
                    private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName'] if instance['PrivateDnsName'] else None
                    ec2info[instance['InstanceId']] = {
                        'AWS Account': aws_account,
                        'Account Number': aws_account_number,
                        'Name': name,
                        'Instance ID': instance['InstanceId'],
                        'AMI ID': instance['ImageId'],
                        'Volumes': block_devices,
                        'Private IP': private_ips_list,
                        'Public IP': public_ips_list,
                        'Private DNS': private_dns,
                        'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'],
                        'VPC ID': vpc_id,
                        'Type': instance['InstanceType'],
                        'Key Pair Name': key_name,
                        'State': instance['State']['Name'],
                        'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly
                    }
                    mongo_instance_dict = {'_id': '', 'AWS Account': aws_account, "Account Number": aws_account_number, 'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance["InstanceId"], 'AMI ID': instance['ImageId'], 'Volumes': block_devices,  'Private IP': private_ips_list, 'Public IP': public_ips_list, 'Private DNS': private_dns, 'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'VPC ID': vpc_id, 'Type': instance["InstanceType"], 'Key Pair Name': key_name, 'State': instance["State"]["Name"], 'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly}
                    insert_doc(mongo_instance_dict)
    mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account)
```

This is the function that inserts the dictionary into MongoDB:

```
def insert_doc(mydict):
    mydb, mydb_name, instance_col = set_db()
    mydict['_id'] = ObjectId()
    instance_doc = instance_col.insert_one(mydict)
    return instance_doc
```

This is the function that writes the MongoDB to the file:

```
def mongo_export_to_file():
    aws_account = 'jf-master-pd'
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    mydb, mydb_name, instance_col = set_db()
    # make an API call to the MongoDB server
    cursor = instance_col.find()
    # extract the list of documents from cursor obj
    mongo_docs = list(cursor)

    # create an empty DataFrame for storing documents
    docs = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[])

    # iterate over the list of MongoDB dict documents
    for num, doc in enumerate(mongo_docs):
        # convert ObjectId() to str
        doc["_id"] = str(doc["_id"])
        # get document _id from dict
        doc_id = doc["_id"]
        # create a Series obj from the MongoDB dict
        series_obj = pandas.Series( doc, name=doc_id )
         # append the MongoDB Series obj to the DataFrame obj
        docs = docs.append(series_obj)
        # get document _id from dict
        doc_id = doc["_id"]
        # Set the output file
        output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv', '')
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.csv')

        # export MongoDB documents to a CSV file
        docs.to_csv(output_file, ",") # CSV delimited by commas
```

Here's a link to the original code directory in [github](https://github.com/bluethundr/jf_cloud_scripts/tree/master/aws_scripts/python/aws_tools). The files we want are aws_ec2_list_instances.py and ec2_mongo.py

Why are the columns and headers out of order in the MongoDB version? How do I get rid of the extra columns added by mongo for the ID when printing to the file from pandas?

Comment: Instead of dictionary try using OrderedDict from collections package

Comment: Do you have a testbed we can use somewhere? I tried running your code, and `pandas` is tough to install, and after that, I cannot be sure that I have my mongodb collection setup just like yours. Your `create_mongodb` is not defined in the repo you posted.

Comment: That's odd. I've added the `create_mongodb` definition back in. Not sure why that disappeared. The script is working now, check out my answer. If you check out the repo again just note that the `drop_mongodb` function isn't all the way there yet, it's still a work in progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas is a very flexible and forgiving library for managing and analyzing data. It is total overkill if all you want to do is convert a MongoDB collection to a CSV file when the `csv` module comes standard, and the way you are using it is very inefficient. The other thing to note is that until recently, neither Python nor Pandas tried to preserve the order of items in a dict. Prior to Python beginning to preserve order in version 3.5, code was written on the assumption that the order of items in a dict was not important. Only as of Python 3.7 did maintaining the order of dict entries become an official language feature.

The DataFrame is the primary Pandas data structure, and it represents a 2 dimensional array of data. Some things about it can be confusing, and I think you got tripped up on the fact that both rows and columns can have named indexes. In general, when talking about data in Panda, "index" refers to the row index.

In your data, the row index would be the value of the MongoDB `_id` and you want to throw that away. That is fine, but it may have led you to think that "index" meant column.

A Series is generally meant to represent a column of data. When initialized with a dict, the keys are treated as indexes, which is to say row labels, not column labels. You will see most of the operations between DataFrames and Series treat Series as columns. But as I said, Pandas is flexible, so they have the `DataFrame.append` function which treats a Series as a row.

The catch is that when appending a row, Pandas expects the Series to be appending a row to existing columns. When the Series has indexes (keys in the original dict) that do not exist in the DataFrame, it adds them to the end of the columns as new columns, and as you see, it adds them in sorted order. This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35092) in the current version (1.0.5) that was probably allowed to go this long without being fixed because dict order used to be ignored anyway, but be grateful for it, because it caused you to investigate further.

Your conversion of the MongoDB collection to a DataFrame by appending Series to an initially empty DataFrame is really inefficient. DataFrame is perfectly capable of reading your MongoDB collection, and does it with far less code for you to write.

Here is my recommended version of `mongo_export_to_file` if you need Pandas:

```py
def mongo_export_to_file():
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    _, _, instance_col = set_db()
    # make an API call to the MongoDB server
    mongo_docs = instance_col.find()

    # Convert the mongo docs to a DataFrame
    docs = pandas.DataFrame(mongo_docs)
    # Discard the Mongo ID for the documents
    docs.pop("_id")

    # compute the output file directory and name
    output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv', '')
    output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.csv')

    # export MongoDB documents to a CSV file, leaving out the row "labels" (row numbers)
    docs.to_csv(output_file, ",", index=False) # CSV delimited by commas
```

Here is the version I would use in a project that did not need Pandas:

```py
def mongo_export_to_file():  
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    _, _, instance_col = set_db()
    # make an API call to the MongoDB server
    mongo_docs = instance_col.find()
    if mongo_docs.count() == 0:
        return

    fieldnames = list(mongo_docs[0].keys())
    fieldnames.remove('_id')

    # compute the output file directory and name
    output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv', '')
    output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.csv')
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction="ignore")
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(mongo_docs)
```

Comment: Wonderful solution! I've learned a lot from your example. Thank you incredibly!

Comment: Awesome! Sure, the only reason I didn't do that last night was that the option to award the bounty wasn't available yet. I had to wait. Thanks again! Really appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why are the columns and headers out of order in the MongoDB version?

Given that the JSON format is correct, the issue arises in the `mongo_export_to_file()` function. First of all, note that the columns are ordered **alphabetically** in the output. One quick-and-dirty fix would be to append a letter to each column name to preserve the original order (`AWS account -> a_AWS_account`; `Account Number -> b_Account _Number`). This would leave the rest of the code intact.

Anyhow, you must have lost the original column order somewhere. Python `dict` doesn't necessarily keep the original order. Following @Shubham 's comment, I would try two things:

1. Substituting the `doc` dict in the first line of the `for` loop by an `OrderedDict`:

```py
...
from collections import OrderedDict
...
...
    # iterate over the list of MongoDB dict documents
    for num, doc in enumerate(mongo_docs):
        doc = OrderedDict(doc)
```

2. If the issue persists, the problem comes from the API call `cursor = instance_col.find()`. Have a look at the contents of the cursor. There should be a way to preserve the order in the JSON. Maybe it is documented in the `pymongo` library ([link to the `find` function](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)), although the `sort` parameter doesn't seem to have any effect.

#### How do I get rid of the extra columns added by mongo for the ID when printing to the file from pandas?

In the export to csv format, add `index=False`:

```py
      # export MongoDB documents to a CSV file
      docs.to_csv(output_file, sep=",", index=False) # CSV delimited by commas
```

Comment: @bluethundr, I do not understand why you accepted this answer. It does not solve your problem of preserving the column order. I worry that accepting this answer will mislead future readers. Creating an OrderedDict from an existing Dict is not helpful, as all it does is preserve whatever order the Dict was going to give anyway. Your problem is that Series is the wrong data type to use, as it gives you a column of keys and a column of values, and the keys are sorted when later converted from rows to column headings. Also, setting index=False gets rid of the row labels, but not the `_id` column.

Comment: OK thank you @OldPro. I will use your solution tomorrow, and I will probably accept your answer. It does make sense.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe).

What I had to do was create a list of filednames and apply it to the DF:

```
# export MongoDB documents to a CSV file
fieldnames = [ 'AWS Account', 'Account Number', 'Name', 'Instance ID', 'AMI ID', 'Volumes', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Private DNS', 'Availability Zone', 'VPC ID', 'Type', 'Key Pair Name', 'State', 'Launch Date']
docs.to_csv(output_file, columns=fieldnames, sep=",", index=False) # CSV delimited by commas
```

Comment: That is an unfortunate choice of solution, as it requires you to now maintain a complete field list and order that is totally separate from the database. When the database adds a column, you will lose it if you do not also update this here. With my solution, you do not lose the order of columns in the first place. (My solution is also a lot more efficient.)

Comment: OK thanks. I will try your solution and see how it goes.