# How to export CSV data file from Mongo DB cloud (Atlas)?

Tags: mongodb, csv, cloud, atlas

I am a data scientist and need to export CVS data file from MongoDB Atlas database for my collections, How can I achieve this without installing compass or any other MongoDB tools?

Answer (score 0):

install mognodb on your local computer and use mongoexport command :

```
mongoexport –db database_name –collection collection_name –type=csv –fields fields_names –out path_or_name_of_the_file
```

Or use this python code :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63044749/11865917

- Sources :

  - https://sqlserverguides.com/export-mongodb-to-csv/
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63044749/11865917