# Sorting dataframe by specific column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to sort pandas's dataframe by specific column names?
My dataframe columns look like this:

```
+-------+-------+-----+------+------+----------+
|movieId| title |drama|horror|action|  comedy  |
+-------+-------+-----+------+------+----------+
|                                              |
+-------+-------+-----+------+------+----------+
```

I would like to sort the dataframe only by columns = ['drama','horror','sci-fi','comedy']. So I get the following dataframe:

```
+-------+-------+------+------+------+----------+
|movieId| title |action|comedy|drama |  horror  |
+-------+-------+------+------+------+----------+
|                                               |
+-------+-------+------+------+------+----------+
```

I tried `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` but it sorts all columns:

```
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
|action | comedy|drama |horror|movieId|  title   |
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
|                                                |
+-------+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: I think your first example and second example are accidentally swapped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set order of columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly rearrange columns like so

```
df[['movieId','title','drama','horror','sci-fi','comedy']]
```

If you have a lot of columns to sort alphabetically

```
df[np.concatenate([['movieId,title'],df.drop('movieId,title',axis=1).columns.sort_values()])]
```

Comment: Not very practical for a larger amount of cols. Perhaps suggest a not hardcoded method to sort the genres?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting all columns after second column and add first 2 columns:

```
c = df.columns[:2].tolist() + sorted(df.columns[2:].tolist())
print (c)
['movieId', 'title', 'action', 'comedy', 'drama', 'horror']
```

Last change order of columns by this list:

```
df1 = df[c]
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) but only for all columns without first 2 selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be set `movieId` and `title` as index of the DataFrame and then sort index by the remaining column.

```
df.set_index(['movieId', 'title'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: And then reset_index. Why not.