# Subset columns and reorder

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I want to reorder columns and select the columns that I want.
For example, if the columns names, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.
I know the simple way is:

```
# Python
df = df[['D', 'C', 'A', 'B']]
```

However, if there are multiple columns, like more than hundred variables, this method is really bad. I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55803252/7651845) of this.

```
# Python
cols_to_order = ['D', 'C']
new_columns = cols_to_order + (df.columns.drop(cols_to_order).tolist())
df= df[new_columns]
```

But the above is not really flexible.

In `R`, using `subset()` is a good choice to reorder and subset columns at the same time.

```
# R
df = subset(df, select = c(4, 3 , 1, 2))
```

If there are many columns, we can also use `subset()` to reorder and drop:

```
# R
# Multiple columns
# Drop columns 51 to 54
df = subset(df, select = c(4, 3 , 1:2, 5:50, 55:100))
```

Is there any function similar in `Python`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have numpy's `np.r_` as a python equivalent to subset both on indices and slice objects concatenated. Similarly to `subset(df, select = c(4, 3 , 1:2, 5:50, 55:100))`, you could do:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[4, 3, 1:2, 5:50, 55:100]]
```

Comment: What do you mean @anky ?

Comment: Maybe `df.iloc[:, np.r_[...]]`?

Comment: `df = subset(df, select = c(4, 3 , 1, 2))` == `df.iloc[:,np.r_[3,2,0,1]]` may be not familiar with R

Comment: Is it possible to do `df.iloc[:, np.r_[4, 3, 1:2, 5:]] ` to reorder to last columns if I'm not sure how many variables? I tried but failed... maybe miss something

Comment: `df.iloc[:, np.r_[4, 3, 1:2, 5:df.shape[1]]]` @peter ?