# Convert DataFrame to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I would like to convert to json format by selecting the columns. And since I have a lot of lines, I can't do everything by hand

I have a dataframe that looks this :

```
 Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4', np.nan, 'Ford', 'Audi A1'],
    'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000, 29000, 27000, 35000],
    'Liscence Plate': ['ABC 123', 'XYZ 789', 'CBA 321', 'ZYX 987', 'DEF 456', 'DEF 466', 'ABC 123']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Cars,columns= ['Brand', 'Price', 'Liscence Plate'])


            Brand  Price Liscence Plate
0  Honda Civic     22000  ABC 123
1  Toyota Corolla  25000  XYZ 789
2  Ford Focus      27000  CBA 321
3  Audi A4         35000  ZYX 987
4  NaN             29000  DEF 456
5  Ford            27000  DEF 466
6  Audi A1         35000  ABC 123
```

And I have to convert to this :

```
data = {"form": [
             {"Liscence Plate": "ABC 123",
              "Brand": ["Honda Civic", "Audi A1"
],
              "Price": ["22000", "35000"]},
{"Liscence Plate": "XYZ 789",
              "Brand": ["Toyota Corolla",
],
              "Price": ["25000"]},
{"Liscence Plate": "CBA 321",
              "Brand": ["Ford Focus",
],
              "Price": ["27000"]},
{"Liscence Plate": "ZYX 987",
              "Brand": ["Audi A4",
],
              "Price": ["35000"]},
{"Liscence Plate": "DEF 456",
              "Brand": ["NaN", "Ford"
],
              "Price": ["29000", "27000"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [.to_json() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). It will allow you to easily convert a DataFrame to json. You can change the schema of the json by supplying the `orient` argument.

This will work well enough, but it will not give you lists for the Brand and Price keys. If you want more flexibility, you can first use the `.to_dict()` function with the same `orient` argument, do your changes, and then convert to json using [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Edit:
Based on your edit, I *think* you want to group by the license plate first? In that case you can do:

```
df.groupby('Liscence Plate').agg(list).reset_index().to_json('records')
```

to aggregate to lists and convert to json.

Comment: Hello, yes I check these function, but not allow, to convert in format I want, like specific column at specific place

Comment: The export should have the same order of columns as your dataframe, so you could reorder your dataframe [like explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) before exporting to JSON. Or use the `.to_dict()` function and then use a for loop to make the changes manually.

Comment: I updated my question and expected output

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

So you want this?

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Outputs:

```
[{
    "Brand": "Honda Civic",
    "Price": 22000,
    "Liscence Plate": "ABC 123"
}, {
    "Brand": "Toyota Corolla",
    "Price": 25000,
    "Liscence Plate": "XYZ 789"
}, {
    "Brand": "Ford Focus",
    "Price": 27000,
    "Liscence Plate": "CBA 321"
}, {
    "Brand": "Audi A4",
    "Price": 35000,
    "Liscence Plate": "ZYX 987"
}, {
    "Brand": null,
    "Price": 29000,
    "Liscence Plate": "DEF 456"
}]
```

Edit:

```
df = df.groupby('Liscence Plate').agg({'Brand': lambda x: list(x), 'Price': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
df.to_json(orient='records')

[{
    "Liscence Plate": "ABC 123",
    "Brand": ["Honda Civic"],
    "Price": [22000]
}, {
    "Liscence Plate": "CBA 321",
    "Brand": ["Ford Focus"],
    "Price": [27000]
}, {
    "Liscence Plate": "DEF 456",
    "Brand": [null, "Ford F-150"],
    "Price": [29000, 33000]
}, {
    "Liscence Plate": "XYZ 789",
    "Brand": ["Toyota Corolla"],
    "Price": [25000]
}, {
    "Liscence Plate": "ZYX 987",
    "Brand": ["Audi A4"],
    "Price": [35000]
}]
```

Adding a custom key at the start:

```
'{\"form\": ' + df.to_json(orient='records') + '}'
```

The `\"` escapes the `"` so form is quoted.

```
{
    "form": [{
        "Liscence Plate": "ABC 123",
        "Brand": ["Honda Civic"],
        "Price": [22000]
    }, {
        "Liscence Plate": "CBA 321",
        "Brand": ["Ford Focus"],
        "Price": [27000]
    }, {
        "Liscence Plate": "DEF 456",
        "Brand": [null, "Ford F-150"],
        "Price": [29000, 33000]
    }, {
        "Liscence Plate": "XYZ 789",
        "Brand": ["Toyota Corolla"],
        "Price": [25000]
    }, {
        "Liscence Plate": "ZYX 987",
        "Brand": ["Audi A4"],
        "Price": [35000]
    }]
}
```

Comment: @Mauris Since "form" is the key for the entire array, just add it on to the beginning. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` and building 'manually' the result.

```
data = {'form' : [
            {k:[str(s[k])] if t == list else str(s[k])
                for k, t in (("Liscence Plate", str), ("Brand", list), ("Price", list))}
            for _, s in df.iterrows()]
       }
```

```
>>> data
{'form': [
    {'Brand': ['Honda Civic'], 'Liscence Plate': 'ABC 123', 'Price': ['22000']},
    {'Brand': ['Toyota Corolla'], 'Liscence Plate': 'XYZ 789', 'Price': ['25000']},
    {'Brand': ['Ford Focus'], 'Liscence Plate': 'CBA 321', 'Price': ['27000']},
    {'Brand': ['Audi A4'], 'Liscence Plate': 'ZYX 987', 'Price': ['35000']},
    {'Brand': ['nan'], 'Liscence Plate': 'DEF 456', 'Price': ['29000']}
    ]
}
```

Which is quite close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Then follow @Jan proposition 1/ group by Liscence plate, 2/export as dict and loop on the dict to reformat. But after grouping you could also reformat inside the dataframe before exporting as a dict : fancier, quicker