# Pandas Dataframe: Function doesn't preserve my custom column order when returning df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I followed this code from user Lala la (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55803252/19896454)
to put 3 columns at the front and leave the rest with no changes. It works well inside the function but when returns the dataframe, it loses column order.

My desperate solution was to put the code on the main program...

Other functions in my code are able to return modified versions of the dataframe with no problem.

Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks!

```
def define_columns_order(df):
    cols_to_order = ['LINE_ID','PARENT.CATEGORY', 'CATEGORY']
    new_columns = cols_to_order + (df.columns.drop(cols_to_order).tolist())
    df = df[new_columns]
    return df
```

Comment: How are you using this function? you need to assign its output to the dataframe in question

Answer (score 0):

try using `return(df.reindex(new_columns, axis=1))` and keep in mind DataFrame modifications are not in place, unless you specify `inplace=True`, therefore you need to explicitly assign the result returned by your function to your df variable