# I have a python script to organize my work spreadsheets, but the new columns are not sorted in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, excel, export-to-excel

I've been using this [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My1Li.png) to work on my script.

The goal is to list each client in a single row but append the unique data to new columns so no data is lost.

The script I have correctly identifies the correct data to append and which data to to keep as is but the appended columns are not listed in the correct order. I need it to group Address A, then Address B, then Address C, and so on.

With this script it is resulting in Street A, Street B, Street C, City A, City B, City C, ZIP A, ZIP B, ZIP, C.

What change can I make to the following script to make it work as I need?

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
 
# Create a Tkinter root window (hidden)
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Ask the user to select a file
file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("CSV files", "*.csv")])

# Check if a file was selected
if file_path:
    # Load the file into a DataFrame
    if file_path.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    elif file_path.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    
    # Convert all values in the DataFrame to strings
    df = df.astype(str)

    # Identify duplicates based on the "Alien Number" field
    df_unique = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Alien Number"], keep='first')

    # Create a dictionary to hold data for each unique entity
    data_dict = {}

    # Iterate through the rows and populate the data dictionary
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        alien_number = row["Alien Number"]
        entity_data = row.drop(labels=["Alien Number"])
        if alien_number not in data_dict:
            data_dict[alien_number] = {}  # Use a dictionary to store unique data

        # Process each column's data
        for col_name, value in entity_data.items():
            if col_name not in data_dict[alien_number]:
                data_dict[alien_number][col_name] = {value}
            else:
                data_dict[alien_number][col_name].add(value)

    # Create a new list of rows with entity and data information
    new_rows = []

    # Iterate through the unique entities
    for _, entity_row in df_unique.iterrows():
        alien_number = entity_row["Alien Number"]
        entity_data_dict = data_dict.get(alien_number, {})
       
        # Append entity data to the new row
        new_row = {**entity_row}
        for col_name, value_set in entity_data_dict.items():
            if len(value_set) == 1:
                new_row[col_name] = value_set.pop()
            else:
                for idx, value in enumerate(value_set, start=1):
                    new_col_name = f"{col_name}_{chr(ord('A') + idx)}"  # Column_B, Column_C, etc.
                    new_row[new_col_name] = value

        new_rows.append(new_row)

    # Create a new DataFrame with the combined rows
    merged_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

    # Print the merged DataFrame
    print(merged_df)

    # Ask the user to provide a name for the edited file
    save_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

    # Check if a save path was provided
    if save_path:

        # Export the merged DataFrame to an Excel file
        merged_df.to_excel(save_path, index=False)
        print(f"Edited file saved to: {save_path}")
    else:
        print("No save path provided. File was not saved.")
else:
    print("No file selected.")
```

This results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMVk1.png) but I need it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxdKT.png). Notice how the expected result groups all Address A's, B's, C's and the script output shuffles them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set order of columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968732/set-order-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Wouldn't this work "only" for tables that contain specific headers? Not all our datasets will have the same headers. This script should work regardless of that.

Comment: I would suggest to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968826/15032126) and use an OrderedDict instead of the standard dict?

Comment: I haven't been able to get OrderedDict to work with this. The end results keep coming out like my original problem